# Stubbing a generic method with different T

Tags: rhino-mocks-3.5

I have a Service Factory with a Generic method `GetService`. Based on what I pass for `T` it gets me a service for that particular class.

Now I have a method, which uses multiple of these services and I need to stub all of them. `Ex: GetService<Coffee> , GetService<Tea>`.

```
mockrepo.Stub(x => x.GetService<Coffee>().Expect(c => c.RetrieveList(coffeeCollection)).IgnoreArguments());
mockrepo.Stub(x => x.GetService<Tea>().Retrieve(1)).Return(testrefDataRefEle1);
```

In the above code, on the second stub I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a recursive mock like that in Rhino.Mocks.  You'll have to create a stub for whatever object has the `Retrieve` method and set that up to return `testrefDataRefEle1`.  Then set up the stub of `GetService<Tea>` to return the other mocked object.